# Cannot find symbol while loop

Tags: java, variables, symbols, radix

Hello I am creating an algorithm to take int x and convert it to the desired base being int y. 
example 7 base 3 = 21.

```
void printXBaseY(int x, int y) {

  boolean active = true; 

  while(x >= y) {
      int a = x % y;
      int b = x / y;


      String first = "" + a;
      String second = "" + b;

      String answer = "" + first + second;

  }

  String answer = "" + first + second;

  println(x + " base " + y + " is " + answer);

}
```

}

at String answer it has error cannot find symbol - variable first, can anyone explain why it cannot find it? and provide a solution.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those variable's are out of scope.

In java  the scope is restricted to  `{}`.

Just move them to top, so that they're available further.

```
void printXBaseY(int x, int y) {

          boolean active = true; 
          String first=""; //  or null
          String second=""; // or null 
          while(x >= y) {
              int a = x % y;
              int b = x / y;


               first = "" + a;
               second = "" + b;

              String answer = "" + first + second;

          }

          String answer = "" + first + second;

          System.out.println(x + " base " + y + " is " + answer);

        }
```

You might be a beginner :Read more about [block and statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html)

Answer (score 3):

It is out of scope. You declared it within the while loop. it is gone afterwards.

To solve this, declare first and second before the while loop starts.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of variable "first" is bounded by while block. So it cannot be accessed outside it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first and second variables are declared inside while loop. So the scope of them are inside while loop only you can not use them outside while loop.

```
void printXBaseY(int x, int y) {

  boolean active = true; 
  String first = null;
  String second = null
  while(x >= y) {
      int a = x % y;
      int b = x / y;


      first = "" + a;
      second = "" + b;

      String answer = "" + first + second;

  }

  String answer = "" + first + second;

  println(x + " base " + y + " is " + answer);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(x >= y) {
     int a = x % y;
     int b = x / y;


     String first = "" + a;  // here is the problem. You declared first and second within the while loop.
     String second = "" + b;

     String answer = "" + first + second;

 }
```

Corrected code below

```
while(x >= y) {
      int a = x % y;
      int b = x / y;


      String first = "" + a;
      String second = "" + b;

      String answer = "" + first + second;



  String answer = "" + first + second;

  println(x + " base " + y + " is " + answer);

 }
```

Comment: I tried that before posting but the loop never ends, thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `first` and `second` as well are declared inside your while loop, therefore its lifetime is bound within that loop.
If it is not clear for you what a scope is, you should read this interesting slide
http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps012a/Winter03-01/notes/Lecture27-4perpage.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
void printXBaseY(int x, int y) {

  boolean active = true;   
 String first="";    
String second="";   
  String answer="";     

  while(x >= y) {  
      int a = x % y;  
      int b = x / y;  


       first = "" + a;
      second = "" + b;

   //  answer = "" + first + second;

  }

  answer = "" + first + second;

  println(x + " base " + y + " is " + answer);

}
```